# Setting a variable equal to a variable that is equal to nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have an array called `my_array` of linked lists.

```
Node* x = my_array[0];
if (head == nullptr)
{
    my_array[0] = new Node;
}
```

How come this one works fine, but

```
Node* x = my_array[0];
if (head == nullptr)
{
    x = new Node;
}
```

how come this one leaks memory? Aren't they pointing to the same thing? They should be the same, right?

Comment: X is a separate variable, which you value initialized. Try `Node *&x` instead to make it an alias

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a variable on its own and it is not an alias for `my_array[0]`. Changing `x` only affects the value of `x`.

Example:

```
int zero = 0;
int one = 1;
int* arr[] = {&zero};
int* x = arr[0];
x = &one;
std::cout << "*arr[0] = " << *arr[0] << '\n'
  << "*x = " << *x;
```

Output:

```
*arr[0] = 0
*x = 1
```

As you can see, what `x` points to is changed but the array is not affected. Now, if you want an alias, you should use a reference:

```
int* arr[] = {&zero};
int*& x = arr[0];
x = &one; // note the &
std::cout << "*arr[0] = " << *arr[0] << '\n'
  << "*x = " << *x;
```

Output:

```
*arr[0] = 1
*x = 1
```

Meaning you should use `Node *&x = my_array[0];` or with modern C++, `auto& x = my_array[0];`.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how pointers work. Pointers are variables like any other and their value is a memory address. Nothing more and nothing less.

This line:

```
Node* x = my_array[0];
```

Copies the address from `my_array[0]` to a new variable called `x`. While the address is the same, the `x` and `my_array[0]` are not the same thing. They are two distinct variables holding the same address.

This line:

```
my_array[0] = new Node;
```

Re-assigns the address of `my_array[0]` to a new address of the heap allocated `Node` object. It overwrites the old address in `my_array[0]` and thus leaks the memory because the address (and the object in it) was never freed. However you still have it in `x` so you can still free it and prevent the leak.

This line:

```
x = new Node;
```

does essentially the same thing but overwrites the address stored in `x` instead. This might be fine though because the original address is still in `my_array[0]` (remember `x` was just copy of that address) and might be freed later. And also you can still free the new address in `x` as well too. So the second one might not leak either.

I highly recommend you to watch [POINTERS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTxHyVn0ODg) by TheCherno. It is excellent and simple explanation.